# Unity: Resolve list of all registered instances of type in specific order

Tags: c#, inversion-of-control, unity-container, ioc-container

I'm registering multiple instances of a specific class implementing some interface (in the example `IInteractivityTarget`).

```
RootContainer.RegisterInstance<IInteractivityTarget>(Name, new InteractivityTarget(Name));
```

I also registered the Enumerable of the type, to automaticaly resolve a list of all registered instances.

```
Container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IInteractivityTarget>, IInteractivityTarget[]>();
```

Now the problem is that I have no chance to define some ordering(-info) to get the items in a specific order when resolvin them. How can this be achieved? I dont want to extend the IInteractivityItem with a SortHint-property.

---

More detailed example:

```
public void RegisterInteractivity(string name, string sortHint){
    if (!Container.IsRegistered(typeof(IEnumerable<IInteractivityTarget>))){
            Container.RegisterType<IEnumerable<IInteractivityTarget>, IInteractivityTarget[]>();
    }

    Container.RegisterInstance<IInteractivityTarget>(Name, new InteractivityTarget(Name, sortHint));
}

RegisterInteravtivity("Show in View A", "aaa");
RegisterInteravtivity("Show in View A", "bbb");
RegisterInteravtivity("Show in View A", "ddd");
RegisterInteravtivity("Show in View A", "eee");
RegisterInteravtivity("Show in View A", "ccc");
RegisterInteravtivity("Show in View A", "aab");


/// --> this should be resolved ordered by SortHint
var interactivityTargets = Container.Resolve<IEnumerable<IInteractivity>>()
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> I dont want to extend the IInteractivityItem with a SortHint-property

You will need some kind of sort-hint, either as property or attribute.

Alternatively, you can create a custom registry that preserves the order.

Example:

```
public interface IInteractivityRegistry
{
    void Add<T>() where T : IInteractivity;
    IReadOnlyList<IInteractivity> ResolveAllInOrder();
}

internal class UnityInteractivityRegistry : IInteractivityRegistry
{
    public UnityInteractivityRegistry(IUnityContainer container)
    {
        _container = container;
    }

    #region IInteractivityRegistry
    public void Add<T>() where T : IInteractivity
    {
        _interactivities.Add( typeof(T) );
    }

    public IReadOnlyList<IInteractivity> ResolveAllInOrder()
    {
        return _interactivities.Select( x => _container.Resolve( x ) ).ToArray();
    }
    #endregion

    #region private
    private readonly List<Type> _interactivities = new List<Type>();
    private readonly IUnityContainer _container;
    #endregion
}
```

Note that we inject the container even though that's obviously a code smell. But the `UnityInteractivityRegistry` is more or less an extension to the container, so I guess, it's justified. Also, in a real world application, `IInteractivityRegistry` would have to be split into two interfaces, of course.